# Splitting in ext java script

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following parameter:

```
UserId=1,2,3,Id=1
```

I want to split UserId and Id. how can I do this?

Comment: is this a string ? can we have a bit more of context please ?

Comment: @Kbell yes it is a string. Right now, I have split the above string at comma which is causing it to split at UserId=1 and 2,3 as separate value which I don't want. I want to split UserId=1,2,3 as one value and Id=1 as another value.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ExtJS-specific problem. You can use the following positive look-ahead regular expression to split on every comma preceded by `KEY=`.

```js
/,(?=[a-z]+=)/gi
```

So you get:

```js
params.split(/,(?=[a-z]+=)/gi) // [ "UserId=1,2,3", "Id=1" ]
```

I went a step further and reduced the pairs into a data object.

```js
console.log(parseParams("UserId=1,2,3,Id=1"));

function parseParams(params) {
  return params.split(/,(?=[a-z]+=)/gi).reduce((obj, pair) => {
    let parts = pair.split('='),
        key   = parts[0],
        value = parts[1];
    if (isNumeric(value)) {
      value = parseInt(value, 10);
    } else if (value.indexOf(',') > -1) {
      value = value.split(',').map(value => isNumeric(value) ? parseInt(value, 10) : value);
    }
    return Object.assign(obj, { [key] : value });
  }, {});
}

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### ES6 Version

```js
if (String.prototype.isNumeric === undefined) {
  String.prototype.isNumeric = function() {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(this)) && isFinite(this);
  }
}

class ParamParser {
  static defaultParser = new ParamParser();

  constructor() {
    // Do nothing...
  }
  /**
   * @public
   * Try not to override this...
   */
  parse(params) {
    return this.__parsePairs(params.split(/,(?=[a-z]+=)/gi));
  }
  /**
   * @protected
   * Override this if you want...
   */
  parseValue(value, key) {
    return value;
  }
  /**
   * @private
   * Do not override this...
   */
  __parsePairs(pairs) {
    return pairs.reduce((obj, pair) => {
      return Object.assign(obj, this.__parsePair(pair));
    }, {});
  }
  /**
   * @private
   * Do not override this...
   */
  __parsePair(pair) {
    let parts = pair.split('=');
    return { [parts[0]] : this.parseValue(parts[1], parts[0]) };
  }
  /**
   * @public
   * Call this to use the default parser...
   */
  static parse(params) {
    return ParamParser.defaultParser.parse(params);
  }
}

class MyParamParser extends ParamParser {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  /**
   * @override
   */
  parseValue(value, key) {
    if (value.isNumeric()) {
      return parseInt(value, 10);
    } else if (value.indexOf(',') > -1) {
      return value.split(',').map(value => value.isNumeric() ? parseInt(value, 10) : value);
    }
    return value;
  }
}

console.log(new MyParamParser().parse("UserId=1,2,3,Id=1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could follow this pattern if you want to create an ExtJS class.

```js
/**
 * @filename com/stackoveflow/questions/59178653/ParamParser.js
 */
Ext.define('com.stackoveflow.questions.59178653.ParamParser', {
  statics : {
    defaultParser : Ext.create('com.stackoveflow.questions.59178653.ParamParser');
  },

  parse : function(params) {
    // logic from above...
  }
});
```

Comment: the problem that I am having now is that I cannot use more than one character to split the string.AlarmDetailsParameters.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(delegate (string s)

Comment: @unhappy_vapor Can you update your question with more details including an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you using the TypeScript version of ExtJS?